# Laravel 6.4: __toString() must return a string value

Tags: php, laravel

I have this simple class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Model\User;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

class UserId
{
    private $id;

    public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        $this->id = null === $id ? Uuid::uuid4()->toString() : $id;
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function equals(UserId $userId)
    {
        return $this->id() === $userId->id;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->id();
    }
}
```

And get this error:

```
Method App\Domain\Model\User\UserId::__toString() must return a string value
```

I`m using:

- Laravel 6.4.1
- PHP 7.3.11

When do a `dd($this->id())` inside the `__toString()` method i get:

```
UserId {#420 ▼
  -id: "b7d24ad1-8dcc-4af1-b50e-c3d569f8badb"
}
```

I also have a replica of this class working in other php project in the same machine, without all the Laravel stuff but i can't understand why is returning the whole object instead only the string.

This is the project i have as a reference and where this code aparently works fine:
https://github.com/dddinphp/last-wishes/blob/master/src/Lw/Domain/Model/User/UserId.php

I check all the similar issues for some time and can't find the solution.

***Update***

I add also the `Post` class:

```
<?php


namespace App\Domain\Model\Post;


use App\Domain\Model\User\UserId;


class Post
{

    protected $postId;

    protected $userId;

    protected $name;

    protected $created_at;

    protected $updated_at;

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(PostId $postId, UserId $userId, $name)
    {
        $this->postId = $postId;
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
        $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();

        $this->user = null;
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->postId;
    }

    public function name()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

***Update 2***

The `User` class

```
<?php


namespace App\Domain\Model\User;


use Assert\Assertion;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use http\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use App\Domain\Model\Post\Post;
use App\Domain\Model\Post\PostId;

class User
{
    const MAX_LENGTH_EMAIL = 255;
    const MIN_LENGTH_PASSWORD = 6;
    const MAX_LENGTH_PASSWORD = 25;

    protected $userId;

    protected $email;

    protected $password;

    protected $firstname;

    protected $lastname;

    protected $created_at;

    protected $updated_at;

    protected $posts;

    public function __construct(UserId $userId, $email, $password, $firstname, $lastname)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->setEmail($email);
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
        $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();

        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    protected function setEmail($email)
    {
        $email = trim($email);

        if (!$email) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('email');
        }

        Assertion::email($email);
        $this->email = strtolower($email);
    }

    public function changePassword($password)
    {
        $password = trim($password);
        if (!$password) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('password');
        }

        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    public function email()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function password()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function makePost($name)
    {
        $this->posts[] = new Post(
            new PostId(),
            $this->id(),
            $name
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since UserId class owns the property why not use the $id property itself instead of calling the `id()` method? And simple type hint it as (string)

```
   /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->id;
    }
```

here's my tested code

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use Faker\Provider\Uuid;

final class UserId
{
    private $id;

    public function __construct(?string $id = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id ?? Uuid::uuid();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return (string)$this->id;
    }
}
```

and my test

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\App\Unit;

use App\UserId;
use Tests\App\AbstractTestCase;

/**
 * @covers \App\UserId
 */
final class UserIdTest extends AbstractTestCase
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function testToString(): void
    {
        $userId = new UserId();
        self::assertIsString(\sprintf('%s', $userId));
        self::assertIsObject($userId);
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard `laravel`, but you are returning an object instead of a string. Access the id instead on the object like so.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->id()->id;
}
```

Comment: I try that as well, but because this `$userId` is used as a typed parameter of a other constructor, if i do that i get an error `Argument 2 passed to App\Domain\Model\Post\Post::__construct() must be an instance of App\Domain\Model\User\UserId, string given`.
Also i insist in the github sample project this is working fine :/

Comment: But! tostring should return a string and then you got a bug where you call the Post show me that code

Comment: I add now the `Post` class as an update, all this is part form a doctrine configuration but i think this problem is not related, not sure...

Comment: "where you call the Post class"

Comment: I add also the `User` class which have a method `makePost()` which call the `Post` class, in the second parameter is where the `UserId` is used.

Comment: But you are setting a database column to a object, that's just bad design. When you save it i guess it gets converted to a string, but before you save it you cant use that column as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the condition on the ternary operator and casting the id to string

```php
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Model\User;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

class UserId
{
    private $id;

    public function __construct($id = null)
    {

        $this->id = ($id === null) ? Uuid::uuid4()->toString() : $id;
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function equals(UserId $userId)
    {
        return $this->id() === $userId->id;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->id();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this before as well and have the same problem than with using `$this->id()->id` :/